# Split request_uri in nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm new to Nginx, I'm trying to do proxy_pass for a specific format of URL.

For example "http://example.com/sync/test" is the URL accessed by the user, internally the URL has to do proxy_passs to apache server like, "http://localhost:8000/test" need to exclude sync, but now it's` redirecting has "http://localhost:8000/sync/test".

Is there any option to split and get parameters after sync,

Suggestions or solution is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the url by removing `/sync/` from the url

```
location / {
             rewrite ^/sync/(.*) /$1 break;
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
           }
```